# Error in .net core with postgreSQL and graphQL to get json column for all records

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, graphql

I am using .NET Core 7.0 with PostgreSQL and graphQL. I am getting an error when I try to get all records from the database using the below code. When I try to get a single record then it is working fine.

**Error:**

> The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<Vcp.Doctors.Gql.Models.ProviderInformation>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
>
> Stacktrace
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsAsyncEnumerable[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at HotChocolate.Data.ToListMiddleware`1.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)      at HotChocolate.Resolvers.Expressions.Parameters.ServiceHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_3`1.<b__5>d.MoveNext()
>
> End of stack trace from previous location
>
> at HotChocolate.Resolvers.Expressions.Parameters.ServiceHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_1`1.<b__3>d.MoveNext()
>
> End of stack trace from previous location
>
> at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I have a JSON field for the `KnownByOtherName` column of my PostgreSQL database.

[image]

This is the C# code that I am using to get the list of records from the table:

[image]

And here is the screenshot of my model class:

[image]

Help me to fix this issue.

Appreciate your support

Comment: Why do you think that the problem somehow connected with the json column? It's not obvious from your question. I think the reason is `ToListAsync` usage. The `Projection` feature can't work with `IList` collection. Try to remove `ToListAsync` call and let `HotChocolate` to get `IQueryable` instead.

Comment: @Eugene I tried with IQueryable and got the below error: The LINQ expression 'p1 => new AdditionalProfessionalAffiliation{ AffiliationName = p1.AffiliationName }\r\n' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: Is `AdditionalProfessionalAffiliation` also a json column?

Comment: Yes, it is.
Actually, there are total 4 columns which has json data in PostgreSQL database table.
sample data: [{"AffiliationName":"test"}]

Comment: I found the related bug in the HotChocolate repo: https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/4429 You can try workaround posted there as a comment